# Ошибка sql php(При выводе из таблицы, считает что в последней строке не правильный синтаксис)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

При использовании данного запроса выводиться ошибка: **"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND us_zayv.idZayv =' at line 5"**

```
$query = "SELECT zayv.".$value." FROM us_zayv 
JOIN zayv ON zayv.id = us_zayv.idZayv 
JOIN users ON users.id = us_zayv.idUser 
WHERE us_zayv.idUser = ".$idAcc." 
AND us_zayv.idZayv = ".$idZayv;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего переменной $idZayv нет, либо там нет значения

Посмотреть всё можно с помощью отладки

[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)

Comment: Переменная $idZayv существует, внутри нее помещается число, при выводе через echo $query выводит: "SELECT zayv. FROM us_zayv JOIN zayv ON zayv.id = us_zayv.idZayv JOIN users ON users.id = us_zayv.idUser WHERE us_zayv.idUser = 3 AND us_zayv.idZayv = 1", т.е. сам текст является нормальным

Comment: Тут одно из двух: либо вы вставите этот чистый запрос в вспомогательную утилиту и там вам детально покажет где ошибка. Либо он отработает корректно и тогда вы меня обманываете))

Comment: Этот запрос находится в функции и обманывать людей мне нет смысла

Comment: если он исполняется - то значит ошибки нет. либо не в этом запросе. где этот запрос находится - абсолютно не важно. тут других вариантов нет либо он верный либо вы **думаете, что есть значения**, а их нет. Ещё раз напомню про отладку